# Unital polynomial ring over a non-unital ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

If we have a unital ring $A$, the ring of polynomials over it always has a unit since $$1_{A[x]} = (1_A, 0_A, 0_A, ...)$$ 
is always a unit. I wonder if there are cases of polynomial rings that nevertheless have a unit even though a ring of its coefficients does not (kind of like in a field of fractions where fractions with same numerator and denominator form a unit equivalence class, even though the underlying ring may not have a unit).

Comment: What do you mean by 'polynomial ring'? If you mean strictly A[x] for some non-unital ring A, then no (e.g. because, considering the natural grading on A[x], it's clear that any unit that might exist has to be in degree 0, which is just a copy of A). But, for instance, let $A = 2\mathbb{Z}$, and consider the ring $A[x]/(2x - 2)$ - is $x$ a unit here? Hmm...

Comment: @Billy Thank you, this is the detail that I've been missing and yes, I meant strictly $A[x]$.